# UWP - задание из книги Джон Шарп - Microsoft Visual C#. Подробное руководство - 2017

Tags: c#, uwp

Начал читать **Джон Шарп - Microsoft Visual C#. Подробное руководство - 2017**. Дошёл до конца первой главы, где описывают как после *"Hello World"* в консоле, сделать программу на *UWP*-универсальное приложение *(До этого имел дело лишь с консолью и Windows Form)*.

Делаю по инструкции простую программу, где водишь имя и она тебя приветствует.
Принял соглашение-разработчика. Затем судя по описанию и скринам из учебникам, я стал работать здесь:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нацепил ТекстБлок, ТекстБокс и кнопку. Посмотрел код на *XAML*, вроде тоже всё в норме.

```
<Grid>

    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Пожалуйста, введите своё имя:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="35" Width="355" FontSize="24"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="userName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,45,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="43" Width="241"/>
    <Button x:Name="ok" Content="OK" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="256,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="62" Width="72" Click="okClick"/>

</Grid>
```

В учебники затем просят сделать пробный запуск. Выбрать ***локальный компьютер*** *(чтобы не искали девайс которого нет)*=> *Отладка* **=>** *Запуск отладки*.
В учебнике говорят, что должны появится мои элементы формы, но у меня ничего не отображает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В правом верхнем углу отображается **060** и **001** *(Пинг?)*.

Думаю ладно, авось не повезло. Читаю дальше. Добавляю обработчик события на клик в MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
private void okClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageDialog msg = new MessageDialog("Привет, " + userName.Text); 
            msg.ShowAsync();
        }
```

Снова запускаю, ничего. Подскажите, где я свернул не туда? Почему не отображается программа, хотя следуя инструкции учебника всё должно быть хорошо.

***P.S. Использую Visual Studio 2013.***
***P.S. Данная задача начинается с 49 страницы.***

UPDATE:
(в коментариях про разрешение)

из учебника:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

моё:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Такое впечатление, что вы работаете с одним проектом (WinPhone), а запускаете на тестирование другой(Win8 или UWP).

Comment: Да, и что вас заставляет работать на не самой свежей версии VS? В VS2013 нет нормальной поддержки проектов UWP. Зачем пользоваться устаревшим инструментом?

Comment: @Bulson скорее всего вы правы. И я наверно наверно не в том файле начал делать проект. Ибо есть Windows и Windows Phone. Введу того что на скринах был телефон. Я начал делать во втором варианте. Ибо в конструкторе первого был планшет. + в учебнике говорят, что можно выбирать разрешение телефона. Например айфон 5. У себя такого поля для изменения разрешения - не нашёл. Вы случаем не знаете где он может находится?

Comment: Про айфон не понял, вы что Xamarin проект делаете? Разрешение устанавливается в дизайнере, в левом верхнем углу окна дизайнера: разрешение и ориентация экрана задается. Если решение включает в себя несколько проектов, то один из них имеет статус (не знаю как в русской версии VS) Startup project. Чтобы задать чтобы проект был старап: прав.клик по проекту->найдите соотв. пункт в меню.

Comment: @Bulson добавил пояснение про айфон 5 в UPDATE.

Comment: 1) Автор книги явно пользуется VS2015, что как бы подтверждает мои слова о необходимости работать в новой версии VS. 2) Там написано по-английски Phone, что значит телефон (5 это размер экрана в дюймах), а не IPhone, разница теперь понятна?

Comment: @Bulson Да, я понял. Моя оплошность. В учебнике сказано, ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ Раскрывающееся меню в левом верхнем углу окна конструктора позволяет посмотреть, как форма будет выводиться на экраны разных размеров и разрешений. То что у меня отсутствует раскрывающееся меню это в связи с устаревшей версией VS2013 или есть кнопка, пункт меню, который её отображает. Как вы считаете?

Comment: Вы надо мной насмехаетесь, что ли? Я вам уже несколько раз повторил про VS2015.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Установите VS2015, лучше английскую, чтобы гуглить ошибки.
2. Создавайте универсальное приложение Windows (UWP), а не wp8.1, как сейчас.
3. В правом верхнем углу отображается 060 и 001 - это счетчики производительности (фпс, цпу и пр.)
4. Не смотрите что в учебнике телефон или планшет, для UWP нет никакой разницы, одно и то же приложение работает одинаково на всех форм-факторах (отличия конечно же есть, но до них вам еще далеко).

Comment: с первым пунктом могут возникнуть проблемы, т.к. на официальном сайте автоматом определяется родной язык браузера и подсовывается соответствующая версия установщика.